# Warning: Contour not rendered for constant ZData

Tags: matrix, matlab-figure, contour

Anyone can help me solve this error?

> Warning: Contour not rendered for constant ZData
>   In contourf>parseargs at 467
>   In contourf at 64
>   In example at 298

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

A matrix with the same value everywhere (constant ZData) doesn't have any level change, so no contour can be drawn.

Example:

```
contourf([0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0])
```

It's no error, just a warning, as some people might wonder why it plots no contour.

Answer (score 2):

just give a close value to the constant value to an element in your matrix. set the rest of them to the constant value and then write contourf(A) command that's it.